# ARKit image detection - many images

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, arkit, image-recognition, coreml

I need to make an app that detects images and their position, and displays `AR` content on them. These images will change during the lifetime of the app, and there can be many of them. I'm wondering how to design this kind of app. `ARKit` can provide this functionality - detect image and it's orientation, and display `AR` content on it. But the problem is that `ARKit` can detect only a limited number of images at a time. If I have for example 300 images, then there can be problem. Maybe I could prepare some `ML` dataset to pre-detect image, and then assign it as an `ARKit` trackable on the fly? Is this the right approach? What else could I do to make such an app with dynamic and large set of images to detect?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding a `ML` approach, you can use just about any state-of-the-art object detection network to pull the approximate coordinates of your desired target and extract that section of the frame, passing positives to ARKit or similar. The downside is that training will probably be resource-intensive. It could work, but I can't speak to its efficiency relative to other approaches.

In looking to extend this explanation, I see the ARKit 2.0 handles (what seems to be) what you're trying to do; is [this](https://blog.viromedia.com/arkit-2-0-continuous-image-tracking-and-object-detection-with-viroreact-6823b94b0eb1) insufficient?

To answer your question in the comments, CoreML seems to offer models for object recognition but not localization, so I suspect it'd be necessary to use their [converter](https://github.com/tf-coreml/tf-coreml) after training a model such as [these](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md). The input to this network would be frames from camera, and output would be detected classes with probabilities *of* detection, and approximate coordinates; if your targets are present, and roughly where they are.

Again, though, if you're looking for 2D images rather than 3D+ objects, and *especially* if it's an ARKit app anyway, it really looks like ARKit's built-in tracking will be much more effective at substantially lower development cost.

Comment: Could you tell me something more about how can I get this positives using CoreML? As for resources, I think, that the model will be generated on the server, and downloaded by the iPhone, when the update occurs.

Comment: Sure! I'll add it to the original post, since that'll be an extension of the original topic, and it's a bit much for a comment. :)

Comment: I know that ARKit supports this already, but the problem is, that I can't just load any number of images to ARKit. At some point it's starting to be too much, and it doesn't work well. This is why Im looking for some additional helper methods to ARKit. As I said - I was thinking about pre-detecting what is on the screen with CoreML, and then after detecting it just starting ARKit method with just this given image, instead of loading all images to ARKit from the beginning.

Comment: Ah! Then the [vision networks offered in CoreML](https://developer.apple.com/machine-learning/build-run-models/) might be sufficient! Worth a try, anyway. It'd probably start with MobileNet or InceptionV3, and you'll just have to supply it with images and correlated labels to train. In operation it takes an image input (of same dimensions as training), and outputs an array of classes with respective probabilities. Then you could---as you said---start the ARKit method with only the top result's given image (or even top few, since ARKit can handle a little; extract accuracy).

Answer (score 0):

At WWDC '19 ARKit 3 was touted to support up to 100 images for image detection. Image *tracking* supports a lower number of images, which I believe is still under 10. You have to recognize images yourself if you want more than that, currently.

As an idea, you can identify rectangles in the camera feed and then apply a CIPerspectiveCorrection filter to extract a fully 2D image based on the detected rectangle. See [Tracking and Altering Images](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/tracking_and_altering_images) sample code which does something similar.

You then compare the rectangle's image data against your set of 300 source images. ARKit stopped at 100 likely due to performance concerns, but it's possible you can surmount those numbers with a performance metric that's acceptable to your own criteria.